# Open PDF in seperate window

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have developed a solution where I have added a content editor webpart on a page and coded a js script to have the pdf files open in a new window. But now I want to copy the same solution to multiple doc libraries, without adding content editor webpart on each library. Let me know some other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the js file in the site collection Style Library. Check it in and **Publish** it!! Then add the js file to the master page of the site.